How can i running airflow webserver by docker when i use ec2 server(aws-linux)
I have tested my project file running by airflow alone
I can open webserver with the below codes and url
Code: airflow webserver -p <my opened ec2 server port>
url: http://<a public IP of ec2 server>:<opened ec2 server port>
(ex) http://1.1.1.1:2000
But when I use docker-compose, I can't access airflow webserver.
So, I have edited port number of docker-compose.yaml like "8080:8080" to "2000:8080"
And base_url, web_server_host, web_server_port of airflow.cfg like.
"http://localhost:8080" to "http://1.1.1.1:2000" and "0.0.0.0" to "1.1.1.1", "8080" to "2000"
however, after this, I did like bellow
docker-compose up -d
I can't still reach to the airflow webserver
what sholud i do?
